# How to generate csr and crt files using openssl in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate

So i'm using AWS Iot and have a server running ruby on rails in the backend. i need to generate some certs for the client and the example on the AWS website only provides a way to do it using the openssl command line. If possible i would like to use the open ssl library in ruby to do this to avoid making ruby run commands in the terminal which may cause issues.
These are the commands i want to replicate using ruby

```
openssl genrsa -out deviceCert.key 2048    

openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr    

openssl x509 -req -in deviceCert.csr -CA sampleCACertificate.pem -CAkey sampleCACertificate.key -CAcreateserial -out deviceCert.crt -days 99999 -sha256
```

The first line i found and think i can do

```
require 'openssl'    
rsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
```

but i'm stuck on the last 2 lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to eventually figure it out using this rdoc example
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to generate a self signed certificate.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'openssl'

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(1024)
public_key = key.public_key

subject = "/C=BE/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Test"

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
cert.subject = cert.issuer = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse(subject)
cert.not_before = Time.now
cert.not_after = Time.now + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
cert.public_key = public_key
cert.serial = 0x0
cert.version = 2

ef = OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory.new
ef.subject_certificate = cert
ef.issuer_certificate = cert
cert.extensions = [
  ef.create_extension("basicConstraints","CA:TRUE", true),
  ef.create_extension("subjectKeyIdentifier", "hash"),
  # ef.create_extension("keyUsage", "cRLSign,keyCertSign", true),
]
cert.add_extension ef.create_extension("authorityKeyIdentifier",
                                       "keyid:always,issuer:always")

cert.sign key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new

puts cert.to_pem
```

[Source for Example](https://gist.github.com/nickyp/886884)

Comment: i dont think this is what im looking for. in my example i am using my own Certificate Authority to sign it. but in your example i dont see anywhere i would do that